# Как полностью переустановить brackets на ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-brackets

Я установил какое-то унылое расширение и теперь он зависает после старта.
Как переустановить brackets? Я удалял просто папку из /opt

удалял через apt-get remove brackets

Но после установки все расширения остаются на месте... Где хранится этот профиль? Что нужно почистить?

Comment: ~/.config/brackets/extensions/user

Comment: еще, как вариант, прямо из меню редактора `Help -> Show Extensions Folder`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить и файлы настроек `apt-get purge brackets`